# Declaring a custom color of a button in Angular Material

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a component *duck* in my project.
In the *duck.component.html* I would like to have this piece of code.

```
<button mat-raised-button color="secondary">
    Button
</button>
```

This doesn't work because *secondary* isn't declared. I can see *primary*, *warn*, *accent* etc. as shown [here](https://material.angular.io/components/button/overview). I would like to have wider freedom of choices.

How can I introduce a new *color*?

I have tried googling it but I couldn't find anything useful. I couldn't even find how they define it in the Material package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible to define a new color in that sense. The available color identifiers are predefined by Angular's theming. You can either change your color palettes accordingly (e.g. change the `accent` color), or simply define a CSS class for the button setting the `background-color` to whatever you want, e.g.

```css
button.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

and then use it on your button

```html
<button mat-raised-button class="blue">Click me</button>
```